# relating columns using DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I cant figure out how to relate a column with another table using the include method.

i have the following models

```
public class Fleet
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public String ownerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccount { get; set; }

}

public class UserAccount
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name="UserID")] 
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }     
        public String UserName { get; set; }  
        public Guid SelectedFleet {   get; set; }
        public Guid? PrimaryFleet { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public virtual Fleet Fleet { get; set; }
    }
```

In the Model UserAccount i have 2 foreignKeys where selectedFleet and PrimaryKey are realated to my fleet table

With this code i do get my UserAccount row back so that i can complete my login, i state this so you are aware that there is actually info to get bakc from the table with the data provided

```
var v = dc.UserAccounts.Where(a => a.UserName == model.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
```

The problem is when i try to include the fleet my record returns null, i know i am doing something wrong since i don't even know how to tell the include what column is supposed to be related to which table i tried `d => d.Fleet.OwnerId == d.SelectedFleet` but i got an error telling me thats not the use of inlcude

```
var v = dc.UserAccounts.Where(a => a.UserName == model.UserName).Include(d => d.Fleet).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: You cannot "configure" `Include`. The model configuration is made in advance with naming conventions, attributes and Fluent API. I don't see attributes and Fluent API, so by default you should have `Fleet_Id` column in `UserAccount` table, do you?

Comment: But there are 2 colums that relate to fleets, the primaryfleet column and selectedfleet, is it possible to have both?

Comment: Not by the class conventions/attributes shown. Do you have fluent configuration code?

Comment: @IvanStoev no, i don't have fluent configuration code

Comment: something like this? `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Instructors).WithMany(i => i.Courses)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("CourseID")
                    .MapRightKey("InstructorID")
                    .ToTable("CourseInstructor"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        }` i took that from an example

Comment: I would add a 'FleetID' to fleet and also add a 'public virtual UserAccount UserAccount' to fleet as well then in your get statement you will not need to use .include. You can simply grab the user account and it will come with the fleet, you would only need to use .include if it is a compound query such as a many to one situation where there were many fleets to one userAccount, but not in a foreign key situation like this.

Comment: Yeah, something like this. Or attributes. You'll need 2 navigation properties because you have 2 FKs.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't understand too well how this relations are supposed to be declared, ill do some resaearch and try something out

Comment: the method OnModelCreating is to create the database? my database is already created, i dont wish to recreate it